# How to create solar flares using Gimp or Inkscape

Tags: gimp, inkscape

How can I create a solar flares effect using GIMP or Inkscape?

Something like this image:

[image]

**Edit**: first of all thanks for all the great comments and suggestions. My initial idea was to create the image based on real surface features of the sun, as seen [in this image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Sun_poster.svg). My steps were

1. *sun disk*: create circle, create granule-like structure using GIMP's plasma effect, then perform desaturation, Gaussian filtering, colorization, and bloom effect
2. *corona*: copy sun disk layer and apply Gaussian filter with large radius (1/3 of image width maybe), overlay layer additively
3. *transition region*: in principle the same steps as for corona, but with a smaller Gaussian filter radius and added bloom
4. *flares*: for this step I did not have any good results, I tried some brushes, but nothing looked acceptable

Here is my intermediate result (without flares):

[image: my result]

Comment: http://www.flamingpear.com/solarcell.html maybe? And lots of hand painting.

Comment: http://rmirandinha.deviantart.com/art/SUN-120232046 Note the first commenter calls it a "drawing." Pretty sure this is not accurate, though it could be a sophisticated brush. This one (http://rmirandinha.deviantart.com/art/WALKTROUGH-Over-9000-202977287) which pretty clearly shows compositing of photographs.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a composite of actual images of the sun from the [SOHO solar observatory](http://soho.nascom.nasa.gov/).

The sun itself is probably a single image and the prominences are probably hand-picked, rotated, and then placed. The "blown out" nature of the prominences adjacent to the sun's "edge" is probably caused by the individual layers being set to a blend mode such as "lighten."

A large portion of NASA's imagery data is "open-source" in a sense, at least the RAW unprocessed type may be. Most of their imagery is actually greyscale taken at a specific wavelength or narrow wavelength band and the colors are
simulated. Even for the "real-color" versions.

Comment: see also: http://hic.msfc.nasa.gov/gallery.html

Comment: I will say though that parts of the sun's body look like cloud patterns rather than the sun's distinct and odd textural appearance.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I did to make this:

[image]

This is actually the moon. I am not sure what the original image uses as a base but I used the moon. The secret to such images is to layer images and set the layer mode to Linear Dodge(ADD). This gives the light emitting feel. For this particular image I used the Liquify in Photoshop. I guess GIMP has it's own feature. The Liquify gives the thicker "rays" by just Smudging the original base image. For the finer rays I "exploded" a simple brush with BLUR->Radial Blur (Zoom). Then a few liquified copies in order to give the curvy rays. Overall:
 - Duplicate
 - Smudge
 - Color mode to ADD
 - repeat :)

Hope that helps.

Step-by-step:

[image]

Comment: @Dominic Sure. That's the beauty of this world. Everyone is different. :)

Comment: As a note - I am not sure what "liquify" is on Photoshop,but it looks like the effect in  `filter->distort->iWarp` in GIMP up to 2.8. Anyone using the nightly builds for 2.9, or otherwise a recent build from GIMP in GIT Master can have iWarp as a tool instead of a filter.

Answer (score 1):

Those flares around the sun are made using fractal IFS flames, most likely using Apophysis - it is also available on Gimp under

Filters > Render > Nature > Flame ...

Hit 'Edit' and select the spherical variation and you should get similar flares. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this inquiry is from forever ago but if you simply make a solid circle on gimp and then go to your paint brushes there are a few in there that will make incredible solar flares by just blotting them inside the circle. Make the brushes just a hair larger and start blotting between red and yellow. You're welcome.